# Formula creation - date comparison

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to construct an Excel formula which compares the date in column A to the date in column B and tells me YES if they are the same date, tells me NO if they are different dates, then if NO tells me what is the oldest of the two dates.

What I have is not working:

> =IF(A1=B1,"YES","NO"&(A1,B1))

Comment: You can just incorporate the *MIN Function* but first make sure that the entries are actually dates. Also make sure there are not time stamps else it will be hard to compare *DATES*.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A1=B1,"YES","NO "&TEXT(MIN(A1,B1),"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

Or if you just want the oldest date without the "NO" then do this (be sure to format cell as date):

```
=IF(A1=B1,"YES",MIN(A1,B1))
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm having trouble as there are quite a few blank cells in column B and it is not formatting to date correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `=IF(ISBLANK(B1),A1,IF(A1=B1,"YES",MIN(A1,B1)))`

Comment: Google How to format as date in Excel:  https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+format+cell+as+date+in+Excel&oq=How+to+format+cell+as+date+in+Excel&aqs=chrome..69i57.11558j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8